# 2 Dojo Dijit Content Panes Side by Side - When Showing/Hiding one, the other will not resize dynamically

Tags: hide, dojo, esri, contentpane

I have 2 Dojo Dijit ContentPane's side by side. I want to show/hide one of them, and have the other one stretch dynamically as needed. I am using an ESRI mapping example which uses 'dijit.layout.BorderContainer'. The "divRightMenu" will show/hide itself correctly, but, when opened, rather than pushing the "mapDiv" Div, it just appears on top of it. I want the "mapDiv" div to dynamically resize itself depending on the visible state of the "divRightMenu" div.

I'm including the full page code below - I have already experimented with style.Display = Block / None, style.Visibility = Visible/Hidden, as well as trying to dynamically set the width of divRightMenu from 1 pixel to 150 pixels. In all cases, divRightMenu appears "on top of" mapDiv, rather than "pushing" it like I want. If I change the code so that divRightMenu is visible by default on page load, then what happens when i hide it is it disappears, but the blank spot it once occupied still remains. Surely this is something simple I'm missing?

In the past (standard CSS), I would combine "float:left/right" with "overflow:hidden", and display:block/none, and could easily achieve the effect I'm after, but with Dojo/Dijit i'm not sure what i'm missing. I experimented with various combinations of float/overflow on the inline styling of the 2 DIV tags in question, but was unable to get it to work. I also noted that one poster mentioned that he programmatically created his dijit ContentPanes on the fly to overcome the issue, but I was hoping for a solution other than this (i need all the settings from the div's content to be retained between showing/hiding the div, and i'm not sure if re-creating it on the fly will allow for this).

Here are the 2 threads I found that touch on the topic:

[Dojo Toggle Hide and Show Divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274282/dojo-toggle-hide-and-show-divs)

[Toggling the display of a Dojo dijit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088839/toggling-the-display-of-a-dojo-dijit)

These mainly deal with being able to hide the div or not. In my case I'm able to hide/show it, but just not able to get the desired auto-resize behavior from the remaining DIV.

In any case, full code sample is included below - any help would be appreciated:

**Main Index.htm Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/1.2/js/dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
var djConfig = {
parseOnLoad: true
}

function ToggleVisibility(id) 
{
//if (dijit.byId(id).domNode.style.width == '150px') {
if (dijit.byId(id).domNode.style.display == 'block') {
dijit.byId(id).domNode.style.display = 'none';
//dijit.byId(id).domNode.style.width = "1px";
//dojo.style(id, "visibility", "hidden");
}
else {
//dijit.byId(id).domNode.style.width = "150px";
dijit.byId(id).domNode.style.display = 'block';
//dojo.style(id, "visibility", "visible");
}

dijit.byId(id).resize();
//dijit.byId("mapDiv").resize();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=1.2"></script>
<script src="layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
</script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
<!--TOPMOST LAYOUT CONTAINER-->
<div style="border:4px solid purple;width:100%;height:100%;" id="mainWindow" dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" gutters="false">
<!--HEADER SECTION-->
<div id="header" style="border:4px solid red;height:85px;" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top">
<div id="headerArea" style="border:2px solid black;height:50px;" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top">Logo Here</div>
<div id="navMenuArea" style="border:2px solid green;height:35px;" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top">Menu Here | <input type="button" onClick="ToggleVisibility('divRightMenu');" value="Toggle Right Menu"/></div>
</div>

<!--CENTER SECTION-->
<!--CENTER CONTAINER-->
<div id="mapDiv" style="border:2px solid green;margin:2px;" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center"></div>
<!--RIGHT CONTAINER-->
<div id="divRightMenu" style="display:none;width:150px;border:2px solid orange;background-color:whitesmoke;" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="right">
Right Menu
</div>

<!--FOOTER SECTION-->
<div style="border:4px solid blue;height:50px;" id="footer" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="bottom">
Footer Here
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**layout.js Code:**

```
dojo.require("esri.map");
var resizeTimer;
var map;
function init() {
var initialExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent(-125.0244140625, 14.4580078125, -80.0244140625, 59.4580078125, new esri.SpatialReference({
wkid: 4326
}));
map = new esri.Map("mapDiv", {
extent: initialExtent
});

dojo.connect(map, 'onLoad', function(theMap) {
dojo.connect(dijit.byId('mapDiv'), 'resize', function() {
resizeMap();
});
});

var url = "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer";

var tiledLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(url);
map.addLayer(tiledLayer);
}

//Handle resize of browser
function resizeMap() {
clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
map.resize();
map.reposition();
}, 800);
}

//show map on load 
dojo.addOnLoad(init);
```

**layout.css Code:**

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
}

body {
background-color:#FFF;
overflow:hidden;    
font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}

#header {
background-color:#FFF;
color:#999;
font-size:16pt;
font-weight:bold;
}

#headerArea {
text-align:left;
}

#navMenuArea {
text-align:right;
/*background:url(toolbar_bg.png) repeat #6788a2;*/
}

#topmenu {
background-color:#FFF;
color:#999;
font-size:16pt;
text-align:right;
font-weight:bold;       
}

#footer {
background-color:#FFF;
color:#999;
font-size:10pt;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dijit/layout/BorderContainer, place the 2 contentpanes inside it, setting one of the 2 containers' region property to "center" and the other one to "right".
When you want to resize one of the contentpanes, call their "resize" method with an object containing the "w" property.
After calling resize on the contentpane, call "layout" on the border container.

Example :

```
require([
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(BorderContainer, ContentPane, Button){
    var container = new BorderContainer({
    design : "headline",
    gutters : false
    }, "container");

    var pane1 = new ContentPane({
        region : "center",
        id : "pane1"
    });

    var pane2 = new ContentPane({
        region : "right",
        id : "pane2"

    });

    var toolbar = new ContentPane({
        region : "bottom",
        id : "toolbar"
    });

    var btn = new Button({
        label : "Change right side",
        onClick : function(){
            pane2.resize({ w :  Math.random() * pane2.get("w") });
            container.layout();
        }
    });

    toolbar.addChild(btn);
    container.addChild(pane1);
    container.addChild(pane2);
    container.addChild(toolbar);
    container.startup();

});
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/vEsy7/

Comment: thank you very much Philippe - This looks like a very clean and straightforward approach!